Terminal from Command Prompt not showing latest updates in VS Code
I'm not sure if this is the right way to word my question, but I recently merged my changes to the main branch of my github repo.
Since then, I deleted my old branches and created a new branch. However, when I navigate to the directory in my cmd prompt terminal, it still shows the files in the directory pre-changes.
I now have to resort to using the terminal in VS Code but I'm curious to see if anyone here has experienced this, and your possible solutions to fix it?

Have you fetched/pulled the changes into your local branches?

Yes, in VS Code all my local branches are exact copies of the main branch

Check what commit you are on. git rev-parse HEAD... Also what git status says about the state of the working tree and the branch you are on.

Regarding: "Yes, in VS Code all my local branches are exact copies of the main branch". It would be more convincing if your answer was, "Yes, after fetching, all my local branches are exact copies of the origin/main branch." In fact, my hunch is that this slight difference may solve your problem.

Or, are you saying cmd prompt terminal is out of date, but VS Code terminal is up to date? If that's your scenario then confirm that both terminals are in the same repository directory. Maybe you have multiple copies of the repo on your machine.
